# Symfony2 - NoSuchPropertyException

Tags: exception, symfony, properties

I have following code setup:

Form/CompanyType:

```
    ->add('employeeCollection', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'xyBundle:Person',
        'property' => 'name',
        'by_reference' => false
    ))
```

Entity/Company:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="employmentCollection")
 */
private $employeeCollection;

public function addEmployeeCollection(Person $employee) {
    return $this->addEmployee($employee);
}
```

Entity/Person:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="employeeCollection")
 */
private $employmentCollection;
```

Since the latest updates of Symfony2 I get a new error when I edit a company and try to update it. (Before the latest Symonfy2 updates, everything worked fine).

Strange is the combination of methods and the property (**employee gets employoo**):

```
Neither the property "employeeCollection" nor one of the methods "addEmployooCollection()", "setEmployeeCollection()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "xyBundle\Entity\Company".
```

Comment: if you copied that error straight from the source, it says "addEmployooCollection()".  Do you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: I searched my complete project for "employoo" but found nothing that match to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has the same error, i found the problem.

Symfony2 has a PropertyAccessor which checks, if the given property name is an array. If it is, it checks that given setter or adder/remover are available.

The PropertyAccessor uses StringUtil, a helper class, to identify and concat the method names.

In this class there is a method which checks the name. If the name contains 'ee' replace it with 'oo'.

vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/StringUtil.php on line 193:

```
// Convert teeth to tooth, feet to foot
if (false !== ($pos = strpos($plural, 'ee')) && strlen($plural) > 3) {
    return substr_replace($plural, 'oo', $pos, 2);
}
```

So using $employees instead of $employeeCollection fixes the problem..